# Testing Koin viewmodel: Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread

Tags: android, android-testing, android-koin

Trying to create JUnit test for Viewmodel using Koin DI. Running the first test I've got this issue: `Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread`. So how should I test Viewmodel correctly?

Test:

```
class TripTrackerPerspectiveViewModelTest: KoinTest {

    private val viewModel: MyTrackerViewModel by inject()

    @Test
    fun initTest(){
        Timber.d("initTest = ${viewModel.getTodayDate()}")
    }

}
```

Viewmodel:

```
class TripTrackerPerspectiveViewModel(
    private val locationManager: LocationManagerInterface,
    private val settingsManager: SettingsManagerInterface): BaseViewModel() {

    val currentStationIndex = MutableLiveDataUpdated<Int>().also { it.value = 0 } //error is here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
MutableLiveDataUpdated<Int>().also { it.value = 0 }
```

you can use:

```
MutableLiveData<Int>().also { it.postValue(0) }
```

or just:

```
MutableLiveData(0)
```